# While starting with react using npm, I installed create-react-app but after that I was not able to make react folder

Tags: reactjs, npm

I first tried with `npm install -g create-react-app` command and then I ran the `create-react-app myapp` command, but it showed the same error as in the picture below. Then, I tried using `npx`, but it showed me same error.

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: could you please add the npx command you tried for better understanding

Comment: It's already in the picture.

Comment: 'npx create-react-app myapp'

Answer (score 0):

Try npm cache clean --force and then try again npx create-react-app myapp

Comment: then try this npm cache clean --force after that run
npm update after that run  npx create-react-app myapp